# локальные переменные

Tags: mysql

доброго времени суток! как мне при внесении записи в таблицу сохранить id этой записи для внесения в другую? я пробовал так:

> $query = $db->query(" insert  into
> `users2`(`name`,`email`)
> values('$name','$email') ,([@a](/users/48/asmer):=id)");

Comment: SQL: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); Можешь применить этот sql запрос после вставки строки. Либо функция в PHP. Как тебе удобнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть функция [mysql_insеrt_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Но она уже устаревшая. Там по ссылке посмотрите, что теперь рекомендуется использовать